# I can't see any way to fully solve this python looping question

Tags: python, function, for-loop

After hours of trying, I was able to get 6/10 points on this. As you can see, the last test (number 4) gets 0/4 points. There's probably some simple reason but I don't know what it is. I can see they're trying to make the input for 4 different by using a list....seems impossible. This is what I have so far:

> When analyzing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human
> weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This can be done by
> normalizing to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers. For
> this program, adjust the values by subtracting the smallest value from
> all the values. Input values should be added to the list until -1 is
> entered.

> Ex: If the input is:

```
30
50
10
70
65
-1
```

> the output is:

```
20
40
0
60
55
```

> Your program must define and call the function: get_minimum_int(nums)

My code:

```
newList = []
answer = []
def get_minimum_int(nums):
    smallest = min(newList[0:-1])
    for i in newList:
        if i != -1:
            i = i - smallest
            answer.append(i)
    for i in answer:
        str(i)
        print(i)

 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        nums = int(input())
        newList.append(nums)
        if nums == -1:
            break
    get_minimum_int(nums)
```

> 1: Compare output 2 / 2

```
Input
30
50
10
70
65
-1
Your output
20
40
0
60
55
```

> 2: Compare output 2 / 2

```
Input
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
-1
Your output
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
```

> 3: Compare output  2/2

```
Input
99
52
12
200
-1
Your output
87
40
0
188
```

> 4: Unit test 0 / 4
>
> Test get_minimum_int() with [30, 50, 10, 70, 65]

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty seq
```

Comment: What is the point of `newList`? Why don't you just use `nums` inside `get_minimum_int`? Clearly, if you just import and call the function, `newList` will be empty and your function will fail with the error message you have shown.

Comment: I think @mkrieger1 is probably right.  If their unit test tries to call your function directly, it will fail, because you are not reading the list that was passed to you.  You are reading the list you input, so if they don't run the app but instead use it as a module, it will break.  Make the change he suggests.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the purpose of newList is to hold all the inputs I received. Initially, I did just use nums inside the function. But when I do that, it poses a problem when I later call the function. The program says nums is not defined. So I found the only solution that worked for me was waiting until the "main" section to define nums.

Comment: You need to change your program so that `nums` holds all the inputs. And ditch `newList`. You may get confused because you are calling the *single number* that is returned by `int(input())` by the name `nums`. Start by giving a different name to that, for example `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code attached. I tried to keep it simple and more adjusted to your code.
The main thing you should notice

1. There is no point in creating global variables here, as you pass the list to the function. The last test fails because you pass a list but use another list (the global one)
2. No need to insert -1 to the list, as it is just a notification for you to end the insertion of input. When it is not a part of the list, the code gets shorter as well.

```
    def get_minimum_int(nums):
        result = []
        smallest = min(nums)
        for i in nums:
            result.append(i-smallest)
        return result
            
    nums = []

    while True:
        num = int(input())
        if num == -1:
            break
        nums.append(num)

    get_minimum_int(nums)
```